# Remote Desktop Connection: ALT key is blocked?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I used Remote Desktop Connection under Windows 7 to connect to a linux machine (Ubuntu 10). ALT + key is not working under linux. For example, in Emacs, I cannot use ALT + X. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure `Keyboard` settings under `Local Resources` tab.
Options are pretty self-explaining.

[image]

Comment: I tried this option and it didn't work. Did you run it successfully in your machine?

Comment: I have not Linux machine right now available, but tried connecting to W2k3 server host and all keys worked on remote machine.

Comment: A pity this answer is fully desactualised. Properties looks now nothing similar to that, and the bug has returned after update. I can't input pipe symbol, which makes the console connection totally useless...

Comment: This is a known bug for years now. For unknown reason it sometimes works, sometimes you have to use Ctrl-Alt Gr-Key to get the Alt Gr keys

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above screenshot of using "On the remote computer" - on my keyboard (laptop) I have to press Function in addition to the command I want to preform, as in:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd> & my desired key